# ERROR: Permission to [some-git-repo].git denied to BG-JIB

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I was recently trying to push a public repository that I am the sole contributor on (it's for a MOOC I am taking) and I got an error I've never seen before:

```
$ git push
ERROR: Permission to my-fanch-repo.git denied to BG-JIB.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The strange part is that I was able to both push and pull as recently as a week ago.  I double checked my ssh keys and verified that I hadn't renamed my repo and forgotten to update my local remotes.  I even tried to re-add my public ssh key to github (NOTE: it gave me the "already in use" message).

My next step was to reboot the Mac (High Sierra 10.13.6) and try again.  On that next attempt, I got an error I recognize:

```
$ git push -u origin master
identity_sign: private key /path/to/private_key contents do not match public
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

On a whim, I ran the same command a second time and was back to square one:

```
$ git push -u origin master
ERROR: Permission to my-fancy-repo.git denied to BG-JIB.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried cloning the repo again in a completely separate directory and received the same message.  In the end, I deleted my existing public key on github and added a newly generated one.  This solved the issue.

While I am happy that the issue is resolved, it feels more like a "hammer" than a real solution.

What does the BG-JIB error mean?  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you check if you had the private key loaded to the agent?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying question!  I did (and apologize for not adding that detail!).  I double checked that the agent was running and that it had the keys I expected both before and after the system restart.

Comment: Hmmm, is **BG-JIB** the GitHub user that has the repo?

Comment: BG-JIB isn't a user attached to the repo or the system.  I am the only person to use this computer since I did a clean install of high sierra when it came out.  I am both the owner and sole contributor to the repository.  EDIT: (As a long shot) since this a work computer, I also reached out to our infrastructure manager to see if this was some kind of network middleware that could be corrupting my keys.  He did not recognize it either.

Comment: It's strange that you got two completely different errors (public key denied and repo not found) at the same time. Sorry I have no idea why this happened now. Just like connection closed by peer error that no one knows why its happening.